# Music on Rosh Chodesh Iyar?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, rosh-chodesh-new-month, music

1) Are you allowed to listen to Music on Rosh Chodesh Iyar?  1a) Does your individual Sefirah status matter such as the first half, second half or both?

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch writes ([OC 493:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6%D7%92_%D7%92)) that those who think that Rosh Chodesh Iyar serves as an exception to the customary mourning practics are mistaken. (That is not a terminology he uses very often.)

Thus, if your "half" of mourning includes Rosh Chodesh Iyar, you should continue your mourning practices on that day.

Comment: +1 for the diyuk, but one may except music which is a later custom in the same way some are lenient on pesach.  Although pesach has a stronger reason, I believe that logic is the premiss of the question.

Comment: @YDK See the Beit Yosef here where he points out the issue is one of counting days; you need Rosh Chodesh to fill up the number 33. Besides, Chol HaMoed is quite different: someone whose relative dies on Chol HaMoed doesn't do aveilut, and we should because of this minhag?? However, aveilut is in full force on Rashei Chodashim.

Answer (score 0):

Rosh Chodesh Iyar is definitely part of the mourning period, whichever "half" of sefirah one observes.  One may only listen to music as part of a seudas mitzvah, such as a Sheva Berachos for a couple that got married at the end of Nissan.

Answer (score -1):

The yesod is 33 days of aveilus overall.

Comment: I have never heard of people that can pick and choose and make up later (e.g., I got tix to a ball game next week. I will go, and then keep an extra day on the 34th)

Comment: First of all you can not choose a random 33 day6s it is a halachic Klal from the Eliyah Rabbah, but you can choose which part of sefirah you want on a yearly basis and change it.

Comment: According to R' Moshe, it's not so simple to change from the 1-33 custom to another custom, but one may change from another custom to the 1-33 one.

Comment: Also, I think you have the start of an answer, but you need to elaborate and bring sources.